# Rotating Specific Degrees On The Timeline

Tags: keyframes

I have this object that I would like to rotate it about 570 degrees, but every time I make two key-frames and type 'r' > 570 > it doesn't make a full rotation. Rotates what looks to be about 140 degrees instead. How do you recommend I get the full circle spinning rotation that's more than 360?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it (imho), would be to go into the Item Properties, change the Rotation and add the Keyframe with the Button to the Right. After that, change the Position in the Timeline and change the rotation and add another Keyframe.

[image: Item Properties]